# Optimizing AWS RedShift query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am storing user details in a longitudinal table with each attribute of a user corresponding to a separate row. There can obviously be multiple rows per user since the data is longitudinal.

I am trying to find all user details of a particular user based on the mobile number provided. I am using the following query:

```
select ws.*
from (select * from user_details) as vs
inner join 
  (select distinct ms.user_id 
   from (select <given mobile no> as Phone) as ls
   inner join (select * from user_details) as ms on ls.Phone = ms.value
  ) as ws
on ws.user_id = vs.user_id
```

'key' column corresponds to the user attribute and 'value' corresponds to the value of that user attribute.

The sample table is:

```
|---------|--------|------------|---------------------|
| user_id |   key  |   value    |       timestamp     |
|---------|--------|------------|---------------------|
|  100    | mobile | 765783xxxx | 2018-09-09 13:40:00 |
|  100    |  email | abc@te.com | 2018-09-09 13:41:00 |
|  100    |  name  | johnny doe | 2018-09-09 13:42:00 |
|  101    | mobile | 456898xxxx | 2018-09-09 13:43:00 |
|  101    | email  | hi@som.org | 2018-09-09 13:44:00 |
|  101    |  name  | janey doe  | 2018-09-09 13:45:00 |
|---------|--------|------------|---------------------|
```

I am first finding user_id based on given mobile number and joining it with the value column and then I want to find all rows corresponding to that user_id.

I have set up DISTKEY on user_id column and SORTKEY on timestamp column.

This table has close to 2 billion rows.

The cluster details are:

**Cluster Properties**:

- Cluster Type: Single Node
- Node Type: dc1.large

**Capacity Details**:

- Current Node Type: dc1.large
- CPU: 7 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores) per node
- Memory: 15GiB per node
- Platform: 64-bit

The query with this configuration is currently taking 160 seconds to execute.

Appreciate any help in optimizing this query and reducing the run time.

Comment: I don't think that query will even run.  Please post your actual query, and format it as code by adding four or more spaces to each line.

Comment: Why that's too many nesting? Plan always goes bad when too many nesting work..

Comment: your query looks a little convoluted, please can you explain your requirements clearly. it will help if you provide example input and expected output

Comment: Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: What is the table's `DISTKEY` and `SORTKEY`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein user_id is DISTKEY and timestamp is SORTKEY.

Answer (score 1):

It is *very* difficult to suggest improvements on a query without understanding the contents of the table nor what you are trying to achieve.

It is quite possible that it could be as simple as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM user_details
WHERE value = <given mobile no>
```

The other part of optimizing a query in Amazon Redshift is to wisely use `DISTKEY` and `SORTKEY`. Once again, it is difficult to recommend suitable values without knowing the data and how it is used, but this query would benefit from `value` being the `SORTKEY`. (But that doesn't necessarily mean it is best choice for all usage of the table.)

Comment: +1- try this (and tailor to your requirements) and let us know the speed. also please update your question with the distkey and sortkey of your table.

Comment: This query is taking the same amount of time to execute.

Comment: Does it give the same result set? If so, this query can be optimized by having `value` as the `SORTKEY`, but that might slow down other queries that use `timestamp`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, will an interleaved sortkey on **timestamp** and **value** help?

Comment: Interleaved sortkeys should generally be avoided. They take a long time to create via `VACUUM` and only provide benefit in a few situations. (In this case, only where `timestamp` and `value` are frequently used in `WHERE` statements in separate queries. If you are frequently doing a user lookup via phone number, it might be worth creating a separate table with just user+phone, which can be optimized for this type of query. The up-side is a very fast query. The down-side is the need to keep a second table updated with this information.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I was evaluating maintaining a secondary table but that could be a hassle. If I understand your previous comment, an interleaved sortkey would help were I to query on either `timetsamp` or `value` but not both together? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: Given that you have over 1 billion rows in the table, I would recommend against using an Interleaved Sort. This is because the table requires a regular `VACUUM` to maintain the optimal sort, and you really don't want to `VACUUM` such large tables very often. I suggest you create a temporary table with just the information you need (`user_id` and `value`?), put a `SORTKEY` of `value` and then try running some queries to see whether you are happy with the performance. You can then judge whether the extra hassle is worth the benefit.